# Variable in require path not working with r.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, r.js, requirejs-optimizer

I am new to `r.js` optimization but a fan of `requirejs`

**build-config.js**

```
({
    appDir: "./src/main/webapp/webresources/javascript/",
    baseUrl: "./",
    dir: "./target/webresources/js",
    
    optimizeCss: "none",
    mainConfigFile: "./src/main/webapp/webresources/javascrip/app.js",
    
    inlineText: true,
    removeCombined: true,
    
    modules: [
    {
        name: "app",
    }
    ]
})
```

**app.js** looks something like

```
if (typeof _JSHome=== "undefined") {
    _JSHome = "/webresources/javascript/edulastic";
}

if (typeof EditorValue === "undefined") {
    EditorValue = "";
}

require.config({

    baseUrl: '/webresources/javascript',
    waitSeconds: 180,
    paths: {
        tpl                    : _JSHome+'/js/tpl',
        underscore             : 'underscore-min',
        backbone               : 'backbone-min',
        text                   : 'text/text',
        jquery                  : 'jquery',
        jqueryuitouchpunch     : "jquery.ui.touch-punch",
        modernizr              : 'modernizr',
        hammer                 : 'hammer.min',
        detectizr              : 'detectizr',
        bootstrap              : _edulasticJSHome+'/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min',
        fastClick              : "mobileutils/fastclick/fastclick.min",
        asMetaData             : _JSHome+'/js/app/metaData',
        highCharts             : '/webresources/javascript/highcharts/highcharts-min',
    },
});
```

When I run
`r.js -o build-config.js` in my project root directory, I'm getting the following error :

> Try only using a config that is also valid JSON, or do not use mainConfigFile and instead copy the config values needed into a build file or command line arguments given to the optimizer.
>
> Source error from parsing: e:/mongrel_mpq/src/main/webapp/webresources/javascript/app.js: > ReferenceError: _JSHome is not defined

Duplicate but without solution - [Require.js optimizer and variables in paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462325/require-js-optimizer-and-variables-in-paths)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if `_JSHome` isn't declared, wouldn't trying to assign it in the undefined check throw that error since the variable hasn't been declared?

Comment: If it's complaining about valid json, try removing the trailing comma after "name: "app","

Answer (score 1):

The configuration you have in `app.js` is a *computed* configuration. For instance, you set `_JSHome` to a value and then use it in the configuration. At runtime, there is no problem with this. However, `r.js` is not designed to *execute* what you pass to `mainConfigFile`. What it does is look for a JSON object that is passed to `require.config` (or `requirejs.config`) and uses the JSON object. It is as if `r.js` were to go into your `app.js` file and copy all the text inside `require.config(...)` and then paste it into its own execution context. When it tries to use what it captured from your `app.js` file, you get the error that `_JSHome` is not defined because *in the context where `r.js` interprets your configuration*, `_JSHome` is not defined.

The simple solution would be to have a configuration which is not computed. However, if you need to have a computed configuration, then to get `r.js` to work with it, it needs to be computed before `r.js` sees it. This could be done as part of a build system (with Grunt, Gulp, `make`, etc.).

Comment: can you please post such a solution ? I guessed this might be the issue, but don't of a way to tell `r.js` of some variables.